# How can I restore the Google chrome text scaling to normal size?

Tags: google-chrome, zoom

I know how to rescale the size of the text and pictures in the Google Chrome browser using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and the mouse wheel. However, I don't know how to reset the scaling back to the "natural" level. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*View » Actual Size* (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> on OS X and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> on Windows and Linux).

Comment: Indeed Ctrl+ to make it bigger and Ctrl- to make it smaller too.